# Multiple Roll Over Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to put an image onto a webpage that changes depending where the cursor is?

Current Code:

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Images/Home.png')">

<div class="HeaderWrapper">
    <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image2','','Images/Home.png',1)">
        <img src="Images/NavigationBanner.png" name="Image2" width="1300" height="150" border="0" id="Image2" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','Images/Home.png',1)">
        <img src="Images/NavigationBanner.png" name="Home" width="1300" height="150" border="0" id="Home" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I was thinking it could be modified some how to use this?

```
<area shape="rect" coords="434,54,495,83" href="index.php" target="index.php" alt="index" />
```

Comment: Question doesnt explain anything

Comment: Your question is a little vague and your code could use some line-breaks

Answer (score 1):

1. Search how to respond to the hover event.
2. Search how to toggle a CSS class on an HTML element.
3. When the image is hovered, toggle the class of the HTML element such that a different CSS class is used. This different CSS class will have a different image.

It might be easier to use jQuery for this.